# How do I make slash commands work on my bot in Slack?

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

How do I make slash commands work on my bot in [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software))?

I'm using [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to have the bot post.

For example, if I type `/giphy something`, it pulls in a GIF image, but if my bot posts the exact same thing it does not do anything.

Comment: Try reading up on [slash-commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you won't be able to do what you're trying to do. As far as I can tell you can't have one Slack Integration trigger another Integration. It's not hard to replicate the functionality of the `/giphy` Integration, though.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that I couldn't find it being mentioned anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Slack is not supporting this feature, because commands are only interpreted when typed in the browser or in the Slack application.
You can maybe workaround this by using a web browser automation tool such as [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) or a similar tool.

I've already sent the same answer to *[How do I set a reminder via the Slack API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940198)*.