# How do I set a reminder via the Slack API?

Tags: rest, webhooks, slack-api

I'd like to be able to create messages that use the `/remind` slash command in [Slack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_(software)) via an API (probably either with an [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) or [the web API](https://api.slack.com/web).

When I post a message via the web API, however, the command just comes through like a "regular" message, for example, `/remind me in 1 month to follow up with the Boss` — it doesn't trigger an actual reminder.

Is there a way to set a reminder (or, more generally, use slash commands) programmatically in Slack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it was added recently to the API: https://api.slack.com/methods/reminders.add

Comment: thanks! ended up using [slacker](https://github.com/os/slacker) like so: `slack.reminders.add(text='test', time='today at 4:42pm')`

Comment: do you know if it's possible to set reminders for a channel or group?
`/remind [#some-channel | @group-of-people] about something in 3 hours`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Slack is not supporting this feature because commands are only interpreted when typed in the browser or in the Slack-application.
You can maybe workaround this by using a web browser automation tool such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) or a similar tool.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link about that?